# How to use `rich textbox` in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

If any anyone working in visual studio on c#, we use `rich textbox` on it for `comments` or `Description`.
Now I am working ruby on rails and I want to use `rich textbox` in it.
And I use below code:

```
<%= f.text_field :manager_emal,placeholder: "" %>
```

and its show me simple `textbox`. How do I use `rich textbox` in ruby on rails.
Kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<%= f.text_area :Comments, placeholder: "Please input your comments", :size =>"45x2", :style => "font-size:small;" %>
```